# Add Custom Javascript to method-renderer File

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, payment-methods, external-script

I have created a custom payment module, and when I click the Place Order button, I need it to run a set of custom javascript functions.  To do this, how do I include a custom function from another javascript file into the /view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/ javascript file?

Submit Button:

```
<button
  data-role="review-save"
  type="submit"
  data-bind="
    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
    enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
    click: processPayment, <--custom method-renderer function
    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
  "
  class="action primary checkout"
  disabled
>
  <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
</button>
```

method-renderer function

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: '<Module>/payment/<File>'
            },
            context: function() {
                return this;
            },
            getCode: function() {
                return '<Code>';
            },
            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },
            processPayment() {
                authorizePayment(); <-- Custom Javascript Function from seperate file
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved what I was trying to do. This required the creation of a requirejs-config.js file showing :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*' : {
             <ScriptObjectName> : '<Vendor>_<Module>/js/<script-name>'
            }
    }
}
```

Then it has to be imported into the method-renderer file:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        '<ScriptObjectName>'
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            placeOrder() {
                //Custom Script execution goes here
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that function in **enable** property of button.

```
<button
  data-role="review-save"
  type="submit"
  data-bind="
    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
    enable: (getCode() == isChecked() && isAuthorizePayment()),
    click: processPayment, <--custom method-renderer function
    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
  "
  class="action primary checkout"
  disabled
>
  <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
</button>
```

Method Render function

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
    ],
    function ($, Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: '<Module>/payment/<File>'
            },
            context: function() {
                return this;
            },
            getCode: function() {
                return '<Code>';
            },
            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },
            isAuthorizePayment: function() { //Custom Javascript Function
                //custom code goes here. You can return boolean
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: I should hvae been more specific.  I want that function to be from an external javascript file that i have created.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect what I originally intended